# Can this graph-ordering problem be solved with LP?

Tags: linear-programming, python

I have a modelling problem that I am trying to solve with LP. (More specifically, in Python using PuLP or Pyomo). I am not terribly knowledgeable in this area and have been struggling to find the right terminology in order to do some web searches, so I am turning to you in the  hope that you can point me in the right direction. (Or, advise me that LP is not suitable for this problem!).

Here is my formulation of the problem.

- There is a graph of $N$ generators of energy ($G_i$) and $M$ consumers ($C_j$) of energy
- $G_0$ and $C_0$ have unlimited capacity (the "electricity grid"), but all other nodes have a finite capacity.
- Each flow of energy $I_{ij}$ from source $G_i$ to sink $C_j$ incurs a cost that can be modelled as a linear function $a_{ij} + b_{ij}x$, where x is the total amount going through that flow. This cost can be negative or positive. There is no cost incurred if no energy flows.
- The energy going through a flow must neither exceed the capacity of the source nor the capacity of the sink.
- All of the flows between **finite** nodes are in some ordering $O = [I_{i_ij_i}, I_{i_2j_2}, ...]$ where $0 < i_n < N$ and $0 < j_m < M$
- It isn't necessary for all flows to be present in this ordering; it can even be empty.
- The energy going through the flows are calculated as follows:

  1. The flow through $I_{i_1j_1}$ is the maximum capacity of $G_{i_1}$ or $C_{j_1}$, whichever is smallest
  2. The flow through $I_{i_2j_2}$ is the maximum *remaining* capacity of $G_{i_2}$ or $C_{j_2}$, once the first flow has been subtracted
  3. ...repeat for all flows in the ordering...
  4. After all the flows in the ordering have been processed, any remaining capacity is satisfied from the unlimited-capacity notes $G_0$ and $C_0$, until all of the finite nodes have exhausted their capacity.

The problem is to find the optimal ordering $O$ so that the total cost is minimized.

Here is a formulation of the problem in Python to illustrate better:

```py
from collections import namedtuple
from typing import List, Dict

# A node in the graph has a finite, non-negative capacity
class Node:
    def __init__(self, capacity: float):
        assert capacity >= 0, "Capacity must be non-negative"
        self.capacity = capacity

# An "internal flow" is from a generator to a consumer
InternalFlow = namedtuple("InternalFlow", ["generator", "consumer"])

# An "external flow" is from a generator to the grid or from the grid to a consumer
ExternalFlow = Node

# A cost is a linear function f(x) = a + b * x
Cost = namedtuple("Cost", ["a", "b"])

############# Initial Data #################################################

# The nodes in the graph and their capacities
consumers: List[Node] = [
    # ...
]
generators: List[Node] = [
    # ...
]

# The costs associated with every possible internal flow
internal_costs: Dict[InternalFlow, Cost] = {
    # ...
}

# The costs associated with every possible external flow
external_costs: Dict[ExternalFlow, Cost] = {
    # ...
}

############# Objective Function ###########################################

def objective_function(internal_flows: List[InternalFlow]):
    total_cost = 0

    # keep track of remaining amounts
    nodes = consumers + generators
    remaining: Dict[Node, float] = {n: n.capacity for n in nodes}

    # accumulate costs of the internal flows
    for flow in internal_flows:

        # energy will flow until either the generator or the consumer
        # is exhausted
        amount = min(remaining[flow.generator], remaining[flow.consumer])
        if amount > 0:
            remaining[flow.generator] -= amount
            remaining[flow.consumer] -= amount

            # accumulate cost incurred from this flow
            cost = internal_costs[flow]
            total_cost += cost.a + cost.b * amount

    # accumulate costs of meeting residual demand or supply using the grid
    # ("external" flows)
    for node in nodes:
        if remaining[node] > 0:
            cost = external_costs[node]
            total_cost += cost.a + cost.b * remaining[node]

    return total_cost
```

Is this problem appropriate for an LP solver? I found a case study ["A Set Partitioning Problem"](https://pythonhosted.org/PuLP/CaseStudies/a_set_partitioning_problem.html) on the PuLP documentation but it requires constructing all of the possible solutions in memory. This is not feasible in my case since the space of possible solutions (all ordered subsets of $\{I_{ij} : 0 < i < N, 0 < j < M\}$) grows so large so quickly that beyond ten or so nodes I can't even compute the *number* of possible solutions using Python.

Comment: Is the cost $a_{ij}$ only applied if $x \neq 0$? Otherwise, it can be eliminated from the input since it doesn't effect the comparison of different orders.

Comment: Maybe you can give pseudocode for how the cost of a given ordering would be calculated. As it stands now, it is not clear which flow is substracted from which capacity – especially in step 3 – and what maximum capacity refers to.

Comment: I have updated the description to be a bit clearer and added some code. The fixed cost $a_{ij}$ is only applied if $x > 0$. This problem relates to electricity; the "capacity" means the total electricity energy that must be generated or consumed by the node.

Comment: Yes, my question is whether this problem is appropriate for an LP solver and how it could be formulated as such. The PuLP or Pyomo aspect is not particularly important. I have updated the question to make this clearer

Comment: This problem is NP-hard: The Knapsack problem can be reduced to it by creating single consumer with capacity $n$, a generator for each item in the input having capacity equal to its weight, setting $a_{i1} = -p_i$ where $p_i$ is the value of the $i$-th item, and setting all $b_{i1}=0$: this will find the best combination of items to put in the knapsack. LP solvers cannot solve NP-hard problems, though they can often give you good lower bounds; *integer* LP solvers (ILP) can solve them exactly (but usually slowly).

Comment: If all $a_{ij}=0$, then based on the fact that the Successive Shortest Path algorithm described [here](https://cp-algorithms.com/graph/min_cost_flow.html) does essentially what you describe and finds a minimum-cost flow, which is a problem that a plain LP solver *can* solve, you could indeed use such a solver to solve this restricted form of your problem in polynomial time.